# Metadata in another language is not trimmed

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am building a music player, and one of my music for some reason has Chinese characters:

[image]

so it doesn't detect the validation:

`(item.title.length > 27) ?  item.title.substring(0,10).padEnd(18,".") : item.title`

doesn't cut it until 10 characters, in my device i can see the characters maybe because it has Chinese language with it, but in when it is printed in the console i get only: ????? marks, I get all the music info from its metadata, so don't know how can I solve this.

Comment: [Ellipsis](https://reactnativecode.com/text-overflow-create-ellipsis-text/) is your friend.

Comment: @moonwave99, it says Not found

Comment: @moonwave99 tierd with ellipsis, but doesnt work either